# Error with jquery in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I get this error:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152;
>   .NET CLR 3.5.30729) Timestamp: Tue, 26 Jun 2012 11:31:22 UTC
>
> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 56 Char:
>   650 Code: 0

```
URI: http://api.apps.com/html/81
```

> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 56 Char:
>   738 Code: 0

```
URI: http://api.apps.com/html/81
```

I cant rely on that ie debugger , cause when i view source, i see line 56 as a long line, and i dont know where the error really is? is there a way to trace the error? what does the error doesnt support.Here is line 56:

```
function send_email(to) {
    if (to.length == 0) {
        $("#email_loader").html("<p>Please enter an `email address</p>");
        $("#email_response").fadeIn(250);
    }
    else {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Email', FA.appID]);
        $("#email_loader").html("<img src='http://apps.com/img/ajax_load.gif' />");
        $("#email_response").fadeIn(500);
        $.get("/inc_appdl_main_api.php", {
            to: to,
            app_id: FA.appID
        }, function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $("#email_loader").html(data);
                $("#email_response").delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
        setTimeout(FA.iframeClose, 2000);
    }
};
function iframeClose() {
    parent.postMessage("closeFA", "*");
};
$("#to").keypress(function (event) {
    if ((event.which == '13') && ($(this).val().length > 0)) {
        to = $(this).val();
        event.preventDefault();
        send_email(to);
    }
});
$("#email").click(function () {
    to = $("#to").val();
    send_email(to);
});
function set_url_target(url) {

}
```

is there a way to debug in ie8?

I looked in notepad++. it points to there: 
char 791
    to=$("#to").attr('value');send_email(to);

whats wrong with it

Comment: i guess its console.log(...) which IE is showing error for... try removing console.log(...

Comment: i removed it , still shows the error

Comment: You need to add additional equal sign. Example: `if (to.length === 0) {` but note this may not solve your issue.

Comment: I solved the issue. All I had to do wa sto open it in notepad, and it showed me the char num / col number.. see the answer that i have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

IE threw an error because of the `"to"` variable. I changed this:

```
$("#email").click(function () {
    to = $("#to").val();
    send_email(to);
});
```

To this:

```
$("#email").click(function () {
   var to = $("#to").val();
    send_email(to);
});
```

IE stopped throwing the error!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the console/developer tools is open when you load the page, or else it will fail when you try to use `console.log`.

Assuming that's not the problem, try liberally adding `console.log()` statements around the various function calls, like so:

```
$("#email").click(function () {
    console.log('call 1...');
    to = $("#to").val();
    console.log('call 1 done.');
    send_email(to);
});
```

Go crazy with it, and hopefully you'll see something in the console like

```
LOG: call 7...
```

with no matching `LOG: call 7 done.`. Then you know who the culprit is.

The error mentions a couple character numbers, and those land you close to two of the `.val()` calls. So focus on those first. Just replace them with a constant.

Comment: Sure it does... Just press F12.

Comment: @lol lol lol.. I've read it. His point is that `console.log` is not defined *unless the console is open*, which is why I started with asking you to make sure it is open when you load the page: https://www.google.no/search?aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ie8+open+javascript+console

Comment: Just in case: If you have **Chrome Frame** for IE installed, then you need to use Chrome's Dev Tools instead of IE's version since that will be blank.

Comment: so the solution is to install that chrome frame on ie and debug it from there?

Comment: No. That comment was in case you already are using it, then IE's console is ignored. However, the steps in this Answer are valid since it's all about tracking down the bug.